# Python selenium get link/click on link

Tags: python, selenium

Hey i would like to be able to access a link for example from the following html code
(to access each profile on the url in the code)

```
<div class="fancyCompLabel" onclick="window.open('https://www.techpilot.de/servlets/supplier/perfect_profile.jsp?lngCode=de&amp;ckey=A4gxuEGikU16YXWt6RMd','_blank')" style="cursor:pointer;">Rathberger GmbH</div>
```

basically i want to access each profile get on the profile do stuff an go to the next profile page.
the following code ive written/ got helped by on stack is able to access the relevant html code but im not able to get the link.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

time.sleep(3)

# Set some Selenium Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
# URL
url = 'https://www.techpilot.de/zulieferer-suchen?laserschneiden%202d%20(laserstrahlschneiden)'

# Load URL
wd.get(url)

# Get HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bodyJSP #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#efficientSearchIframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".hideFunctionalScrollbar #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
#wd.switch_to.default_content()  # you do not need to switch to default content because iframe is closed already
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fancyCompLabel")))

results = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".fancyCompLabel")

''' #prints text (e.g. Rathberger) here i would like to acess the link instead
for profil in results:
   print(profil)
'''   
wd.close()
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the link in the `onclick` attribute you can use `.get_attribute("onclick")`. To parse the text from onclick attribute you could split the string into an array on the `'` character and return the index that contains the url, `.split("'")[1]`.

See below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

time.sleep(3)

# Set some Selenium Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
# URL
url = 'https://www.techpilot.de/zulieferer-suchen?laserschneiden%202d%20(laserstrahlschneiden)'

# Load URL
wd.get(url)

# Get HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bodyJSP #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#efficientSearchIframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".hideFunctionalScrollbar #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
#wd.switch_to.default_content()  # you do not need to switch to default content because iframe is closed already
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fancyCompLabel")))

results = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector(".fancyCompLabel")

''' #prints text (e.g. Rathberger) here i would like to acess the link instead
for profil in results:
   print(profil)
'''   
for profil in results:
   print(profil.get_attribute("onclick").split("'")[1])

wd.close()
```